# Model validation in Yesod

Tags: haskell, yesod

I'd like to define a constraint on a field so reserved words are not valid. How can I accomplish this in Yesod?

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
module Sid where

import Control.Exception
import Data.List
import Database.Persist.TH
import Data.Aeson.TH
import Text.Show
import Text.Read
import Data.Text

data Sid = Sid Text
         deriving (Show, Read)

reserved :: [Text]
reserved = ["abc","def"]

allowedSid :: Text -> Sid
allowedSid a = (assert (notElem a reserved)) Sid a

derivePersistField "allowedSid"
deriveJSON defaultOptions ''allowedSid
```

Answer (score 4):

I'd do this in normal Haskell instead: create a newtype wrapper with some smart constructors. This would look something like:

```
newtype Sid = Sid Text

mkSid :: Text -> Maybe Sid
mkSid t = if t `elem` reserved then Nothing else Just t
```

Put this code in a module, and don't export the `Sid` data constructor.